# Xcode 5 upgrade xib to iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

So I am converting my pre-iOS 7 project.  When I open it using Xcode 5 and go to individual xib file, it does not ask me to upgrade the xib.  I do want to upgrade all xib files.

Should I need to be concerned with this at all?

Comment: If you upgrade your xibs then you lose background compatibility (or you can make separate xibs for pre-iOS7), isn't it better to support new features in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about the format of the nib/storyboard formats.

Xcode will upgrade their structure lazily once you actually open them in Xcode 5. This has nothing to do with supporting iOS7, as both upgraded nib files and Xcode 4.X nib files will all use the same iOS7 widgets when the project is compiled against the iOS7 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your `.xib` files to ios7 is fairly simple, all you have to do is go to your project navigator (blue page that should be at the top of your left sidebar), then click on your project, then click `info` at the top of the screen. Where you see `iOS deployment target`, change it to `7.0` (the path is `Project manager> project> info> deployment target`):

[image: Project manager> project> info> deployment target]

now, you should be able to update your `.xib` files to ios7. Good luck!

Comment: This does not updates the xib, it changes the deployment target. Older xib formats will also use the iOS7 widgets if compiled against the iOS7 SDK.

Comment: @LeoNatan It doesn't change them, but it allows you to. It's what I used